# Hermit Spline Tangents estimation

Tags: math, interpolation, spline, least-squares, estimation

[Hermite Spline tangent estimation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbNZN.png)

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm or method that will allow me to estimate the tangent's magnitude (the direction is given) such as the interpolated spline will be the best fit for a given curve (blue dots)
In general points are in 3D space, but even a 2D solution will put me on track.

this is the Hermit Spline form:

**Vector3D p0, p1, m0 (tangent at p0), m1 (tangent at p1)**

**p** = (2*t^3 - 3*t^2 + 1)***p0** + (t^3-2*t^2+t)***m0** + (3*t^2 - 2*t^3)***p1** + (t^3-t^2)***m1**;

My intuition suggest me some sort of least squares method using m0 and m1 magnitudes as the unknowns (could I apply least squares to each coordinates ecuation?) but somehow it should involve projecting and transforming that spline equation over the vector p1-p0 and instead of returning a 3D point, just the distance of that point to the base p1-p0. But I guess I got lost there :(

Perhaps the solution is easy and I would really love some light into this darkness.
Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: How is target curve defined?

Comment: OMG I have just solve it! it works awesome, will post the solution soon!

Comment: I guess you forgot to post it?